# Lib SDL C++ Why wont my app compile with -static and libc

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, sdl

I am trying to learn how to use SDL and I've been trying to get my app to run on other systems. when I try to compile using `g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static` I get a massive bunch of SDL errors saying undefined and the app doesn't finish compiling. However when running without -static it will compile but not include libc. How would I fix this issue while still being able to run on other systems without them installed?

I am also using MinGW-w64 for GCC

Comment: Just link dynamically and distribute your compilers runtime libraries with your application.

Comment: I am not sure how to do than and also it's probably better to statically link the runtime since then it can add all the runtimes required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some flags. Running `pkg-config --libs --static sdl2` will tell you the right flags.

If you don't have pkg-config installed (you could get it from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075)), you can look up the flags manually in the file called `sdl2.pc`, which is shipped with SDL2.

For me this command prints `-L/mingw64/lib -lSDL2main -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -lmingw32 -ldinput8 -lshell32 -lsetupapi -ladvapi32 -luuid -lversion -loleaut32 -lole32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -luser32 -lm -Wl,--no-undefined -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows`.

You also need `-static`, even though it doesn't appear in the output. You can remove `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`, since they're implied by `-static`.

Comment: that seems to include SDL2 but doesn't include libc in the build so in the end still doesnt work on other computers

Comment: @user19227467 You still need `-static`; I've edited the answer to say it explicitly. Why do you mention "libc"? I don't think it exists on Windows.

Comment: it works now using `-static`, thanks

Comment: libc seems to exist on windows. im not sure what it is but i got that error when testing on other computers

Comment: @user19227467 What error did you get exactly?

Comment: they were pop-ups when running saying files such as libstdc++-6.dll were missing

Comment: @user19227467 Yep, but that's libstdc++, not libc.

Comment: i guess that might have been it then, i probably just read it without thinking. sorry